# Render twig template

Tags: php, view, twig, render

I am trying to use Twig in my native php application for rendering templates. And i have some problems with it.

I have next View class

```
class View
{
    protected Environment $twig;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $loader = new FilesystemLoader(__DIR__ . '/../../views');
        $this->twig = new Environment($loader, ['auto_reload' => true]);
    }

    public function render(string $template, array $data = [])
    {
        return $this->twig->render($template, $data);
    }
}
```

And in my methods in controller i use it like this

```
echo $this->view->render(
            '/user/index.twig',
            [
                'users' => $users,
            ]
        );
```

But i want not to use echo, but use return. And when i try to use 'return' my views not rendered. Only blank page with no errors. What do i need to do so i can use return instead of echo?

Comment: "I want not to use echo, but use return" - who would you return to? Eventually someone somewhere is going to need to echo or print something to the stream. Do you have something like a kernel that orchestrates everything? If so, you could return to it and then echo there.

Comment: Chris Haas is right, you always have to echo, print or exit. Look at Symfony's Response class: https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/6.3/Response.php#L410

Comment: Even if you did the return then you would still need to echo the result eventually

Comment: @Geert OP is probably not using `symfony` though

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I think I got the idea you were trying to convey

Comment: Please show the controller, it's hard to understand why you use `echo` without the surrounding code.